An inequality that may be of isoperimetric nature
I am trying to prove the following inequality: let $f,g:S^1\to R$ (here $S^1$ is the unit circle parametrized by arc-length) be differentiable and have zero mean. Then
$$
4\pi \int f(t) g(t)\, dt \le \left(\int \sqrt{f^2(t) + g'^2(t) }\, dt \right)^2.
$$
The inequality is easy to show if the $4\pi$ on the left-hand side is replaced by $1$. The $4\pi$ seems to be related to an isoperimetric inequality. An equality is obtained for $f(t) = g(t) = \sin t$.

Do you perhaps want to have $f'^2$ on the right instead of $f^2$?

"The inequality is easy to show if the $4\pi$ on the left-hand side is replaced by $1$." -- How is this done?

@IosifPinelis Cauchy--Schwarz + Wirtinger's inequality, for example.

@AlekseiKulikov Not clear to me how you use Wirtinger. On the RHS you have an $L^1$-norm. I guess it is $f$, not $f'$.

@GiorgioMetafune you are absolutely right, it is indeed $L^1$-norm. I see how to get some constant with a bit of suffering, but not sure if I can get $1$...

Since $f$ has zero mean, we have $f=F'$ for a continuous $F$ on the circle. Then for the curve $\gamma(t)=(F(t), g(t)) $ the integral $\int \sqrt{F'^2+g'^2}$ is the length, and the integral $\int fg=\int gdF$ is the oriented enclosed area. Thus it is a variant of isoperimetric inequality. It may be deduced from the usual isoperimetric, for example, by the following steps:

approximate $F', g'$ uniformly by piecewise constant functions (or trigonometric polynomials if you prefer) with zero mean;

now our curve is a finite union of simple loops;

apply isoperimetric inequality for each loop and sum up. It remains to use the bound "the sum of squares does not exceed the square of the sum" for the lengths of loops.



Thanks! This seems to nail it indeed,
